# JQuery Mobile+Phone Gap: How to implement a (table) list view with 2 sections

Tags: jquery, android, iphone, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have implemente table view using **`JQuery Mobile+Phone Gap`**

```
<ul data-role="listview">
  <li data-role="list-divider">A</li>
  <li><a href="index.html">Adam Kinkaid</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html">Alex Wickerham</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html">Avery Johnson</a></li>
  <li data-role="list-divider">B</li>
  <li><a href="index.html">Bob Cabot</a></li>

 </ul>
```

It shows  only table view with one section

I need to implement a ***`(table) list view with multiple sections`***

and set ***`the headers for the table view`*** sections

How it is possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/eFEjL/

```
<ul data-role="listview">
                <ul data-role="listview">
  <li data-role="list-divider">A</li>
  <li><a href="index.html">Adam Kinkaid</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html">Alex Wickerham</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html">Avery Johnson</a></li>
  <li data-role="list-divider">B</li>
  <li><a href="index.html">Bob Cabot</a></li>
<u1>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the **List-Divider** element : http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/lists/lists-divider.html.

Like here :

```
<ul data-role="listview">
  <li data-role="list-divider">A</li>
  <li><a href="index.html">Adam Kinkaid</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html">Alex Wickerham</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html">Avery Johnson</a></li>
  <li data-role="list-divider">B</li>
  <li><a href="index.html">Bob Cabot</a></li>
<u1>
```

Comment: thank u very much for ur response your post is helped me a lot thank u

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
<ul data-role="listview">
  <li data-role="list-divider">A</li>
  <li><a href="index.html">Adam Kinkaid</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html">Alex Wickerham</a></li>
  <li><a href="index.html">Avery Johnson</a></li>
  <li data-role="list-divider">B</li>
  <li><a href="index.html">Bob Cabot</a></li>
<u1>
```

AN check this link,,
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/index.html#/demos/1.1.0/docs/lists/index.html